# JQuery Colorbox - link last image in slideshow

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am looking for a way to link the last image in my slideshow to a new page on my website.

The example page is here
http://newsite.wrcolo.com/products/

Click any of the photos and a slide show will launch - the last image says "want to see more possibilities?" and it needs to link to a page on my site (ie close colorbox).

Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline content for such cases.  Simply add a hidden html block to the foot of your page which will be used for the content of your colorbox.

To point your last image to the inline content, change the last colorbox link to:

```
<a class="seating" title="Want to see more possibilities?" href="#seemore" data-mce-href="/assets/more.gif">#</a>
```

You'll need to tell colorbox to use links starting with a hash as inline content.  Add this to your scripts.js file:

```
$('[href^="#"]').colorbox({inline:true});
```

Then your inline content:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="seemore">
        <a href="http://newsite.wrcolo.com/more-possibilites">
            <img src="http://newsite.wrcolo.com/assets/more.gif">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```